# Como remover as barras invertidas (\) e aspas (") de um string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, regex

Gostaria de prevenir o uso desses caracteres em uma *string*. Acho que a forma mais elegante seria por expressão regular, mas não entendo nada sobre como montar uma.

Um `replace()` também ajudaria.

Comment: Pode ser mais especifico e dar um exemplo onde tem uma "\" numa string?

Comment: Foi um caso bem específico onde um usuário cadastrou uma informação na planilha com essa barra ai. Quando fui importar deu erro. Parece que foi erro de digitação mesmo, porém devo previnir.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para testar se uma string tem `\` ou `"` pode fazer assim:

```
/[\\"]/g.test('Olá\ bom dia'); // dá true
/[\\"]/g.test('Olá "bom dia"'); // dá true
/[\\"]/g.test('Olá bom dia'); // dá false
```

Para testar pode usar isto na consola desta página:

```
var st = $('#question-header a').text();
/[\\"]/g.test(st); // true
```

Na regex usei `[\\"]` e o modificador "g" que serve para mais do que uma ocurrência. Se só quer saber "se há ou não" pode tirar.
Os parentesis retos criam uma lista de caracteres a procurar, e dento tem a barra (que tem de ser escapada, daí ter 2), e as aspas.

**Para remover estes caracteres**, pode fazer assim:

```
string.replace(/[\\"]/g, '');
```

Se quiser testar com a consola desta página faça este paste na consola:

```
$('#question-header a').text().replace(/[\\"]/g, '')
```

Comment: Usar listas é bem vantajoso para não ter de escapar o escape que está escapando outro escape ( \\\\ ). ^_^

Comment: Sérgio não entendi como posso utilizar essa expressão para de fato remover os caracteres. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, distração minha, não vi que queria remover! Pode fazer assim: `string.replace(/[\\"]/g, '')` vou editar na resposta

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Daí, para remover basta utilizar o método `replace` com esta RegEx por '' e manter o `/g` para que substitua todas as ocorrências

Comment: @Sergio, para substituir uma barra "\" por duas "\\", como seria?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo pode colocar aqui o exemplo do que quer fazer?

Comment: Quando envio do js via ajax pro controller do C# dá erro numa string nesse formato: "C:\Documentos\Fotos\foto.jpg". Pra contornar esse erro eu quero dar um replace que transforme a string em "C:\\Documentos\\Fotos\\foto.jpg" pro controller aceitar.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo estás a usar `JSON.stringify` para escapar esses caracteres? isso deve solucionar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Dando uma opção manual que pode começar ser melhor se você tiver que fazer mais de um `replace()`. As pessoas olham uma chamada de função e não sabem da ineficiência dela, parece que porque é curto é rápido.

RegEx pode ser até mais eficiente em alguns casos, mas não todos, aquilo é um mecanismo extremamente sofisticado. Não vou fazer um *benchmark* para ver se é o caso desse exemplo porque estou dando uma solução geral que será melhor em vários cenários, mesmo que não dê neste.

Note que existe uma situação que a pergunta não fala, então não tratei, mas seria bom ver se isso é importante. Se o caractere que será eliminado tem espaço antes e depois, provavelmente desejará apagar um deles. Se quiser isso precisa ter um controle se o último caractere que pegou é um espaço, então o próximo não deveria ser, provavelmente apenas se houve a remoção de um caractere. Não vou fazer porque pode não ser o desejado.

```js
texto= "Aqui tem uma barra\\ e \" também";
var novoTexto = "";
for (var i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) if (texto[i] !== "\"" && texto[i] !== "\\") novoTexto += texto[i];
console.log(novoTexto);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/RemoveChars.js).

Answer (score 0):

voce pode usar o replace():

```
str.replace('Item a ser removido', "O que sera colocado no lugar");
```

no seu caso:

```
str.replace('"', ""); //para remover a (")
str.replace('\', ""); //para remover a (\)
```

Comment: Por que está removendo duas `"` em vez de uma só? E a barra invertida precisa de escape na string, do jeito que está é um erro de sintaxe (experimente).

Comment: Esse método só remove uma ocorrência, para mais ocorrências, é melhor usar regex global

Answer (score -1):

Pra remover a barra de uma Str vc pode fazer o seguinte

```
texto= "Essa str tem uma barra\ não sei pq"
texto1= texto.replace("\\", "")
print(texto1)

Essa str tem uma barra não sei pq
```